# Why isn't this an infinite loop?

Tags: c

Why doesn't the following loop run infinite times? I expect that upon reaching 65535, `i` should overflow back to zero.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    short int i = 0;  //(assume short int is 2 bytes)
    for(i<=5 && i>=-1; ++i; i>0)
        printf("%u\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

What about this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=1, y=1;
    for(; y; printf("%d %d\n", x, y))
    {
        y = x++ <= 5;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine and prints

```
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 0
```

What makes it to terminate?

Comment: This is undefined behavior and compiler can do do that in its way!!!

Comment: I don't think it is an undefined behaviour . Loop is terminating simply because terminating condition has been reached due to overflow.

Comment: Re: edit.  "What makes it terminate?"  The fact that `y` becomes `0`.

Comment: What's `i<=5 && i>=-1` supposed to do? It's in the initialization section. I suggest that you read carefully what `for` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are relying on signed overflow here, which invokes **undefined behvaiour**.  The compiler would be well within its rights to optimize this to an infinite loop, or not, or to do something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons.

Firstly, as Oli Charlesworth pointed out, you're invoking undefined behaviour.

Then, 65535 to 0 is an **unsigned** overflow, but you have a **short (signed) int**, so you (might!) have a **signed** overflow from 32767 to -32768. So your `if` condition might fail.

Your printing `i` as an unsigned converts it to unsigned only within the `printf`, preventing you from realizing what might be happening. On my system I get, with no optimizations,

```
...
32764
32765
32766
32767
4294934528 <-- this is -32768
4294934529 <-- this is -32767, we're going backwards...
4294934530
4294934531
...
4294967295 <-- and this is -1, and your condition fails, and the loop exits.
```

**But there is no guarantee that this will always happen with all compilers and platforms!**

Answer (score 0):

How many times a loop runs depends on loop's decision making part and in for loop this part is the middle one where you have put `++i`
and you are right when the overflow occur the value of `++i` returns 0 and 0 is equal to false in C . so the loop terminates.

Try this and your loop will run infinite time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    short int i = 0;  //(assume short int is 2 bytes)
    for(i<=5 && i>=-1; ;++i  )
        printf("%u\n", i);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: why would this invokes undefined behaviour ? It will simply run an infinite loop 0 to short int's limit at start and then due to overflow it will start from negativ number ( again short int's limit ) to the positive short int limit .

Comment: Because the `++i` causes signed overflow, at which point all bets are off, technically.

Comment: loop will always run in this way i= 0 to i=32767 and after the overflow `i` will will have value of -32768 and then loop will always run for i = -32768 to i = 32767

Comment: In practice, probably yes.  In theory, not necessarily.  If your program invokes undefined behaviour (which it does), then you can't guarantee anything about what it will do.

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on the limitation of short int to limit the value instead of defining the limitation yourself? That's very poor practice, as compilers have no rules pertaining to dealing with values outside their bounds. A smart compiler would simply throw an error once it overflowed. Don't do that.

And why would you want an infinite loop anyways?

Comment: I think this is an attempt to explore the boundary of the language, rather than doing something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition statement is *++i*, when this returns 0, your loop terminates. The *i > 0* does nothing and your for loop initialiser does nothing. Your **for** loop is equivalent to

```
for( ; (++i) != 0; )
```